# Android per developer variables

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

My team work with Git and now we are building an android app. This app consumes our webservice, which every developer builds in it's own computer while developing.

Since we can't use `localhost` inside the app (since it points to the device itself), we must specify the network address (e.g. `192.168.1.123`), by now it's hardcoded. The problem is that, mostly, our network addresses aren't the same and then each developer must manually edit the address in order to code.

I'm trying to figure out more interesting ways to do this process. My first guess was that I could do something like Rails' `config/application.yml` or like Spring Boot's `application.properties`. This file would be in `.gitignore` and, when setting up its dev environment, each developer would set it's network address in a variable there. This approach is nice mainly because we can setup this file in CI servers, then the deploy can be automated in production environments (e.g. pointing to `my-aplication.com` instead of the developer network address).

Another way that I've been thinking is to use something like `my-application.dev` and let the host machine (when using emulator) resolve in it's hosts file, looping back. There are two main problems in this approach: a) we'd like to keep settings inside the project's folder. b) When deploying to production, we would to manually edit this.

So, there are any way to do this? Keeping in mind that we appreciate to have this settings inside project's folder and not IDE-dependent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Define a property in `gradle.properties`, in the project root directory, that contains the IP address in question, such as:

```
DEV_SERVER_URL=https://192.168.1.123
```

Step #2: In your `app/build.gradle` file, expose that property via `buildConfigField`, or possibly via `resValue`, to make it available to the Java code via `BuildConfig` or a string resource. For extra credit, use the property only in the `debug` build type, using the production value in `release` (presumably pointing to the production Web server). For example:

```
    debug {
      buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"'+DEV_SERVER_URL+'"'
    }

    release {
      buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://prod.this-is-so-fake.com"'
    }
```

Step #3: Modify the Java code to refer to the `BuildConfig` field or the string resource that you set up in Step #2.

Comment: Huh, 1 second late after the legend's answer

Comment: @AntonShkurenko: My apologies. I will aim to type... more... slowly... in... the... future... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Define `Properties`

```
def Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file('app/custom.properties')))
```

Later:

```
buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_FIELD", '"'+props['customFieldName']+'"'
```

Your `custom.properties` should contain something like:

```
customFieldName=customString
```